# Verb for splitting something into eighths

Tags: word-request, verbs

Can you complete the following with the right verb:

**Half** it (1/2)
**Quarter** it (1/4)
.......it (1/8)

Comment: See EL&U: [Halved, quartered...what's next?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613786/halved-quartered-whats-next)

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no correct verb to fit there in English.

While the verb "to eighth" has some currency, it is not normally used. Instead you should say "divide into eight (parts)". or "divide by eight" or rephrase to avoid the problem.

Comment: You could say you are to halve it and then quarter each half.

Comment: That would be one possible rephrasing.

Comment: Anyone using the verb *eighthed* should be drawn and quartered. *And subsequently halved!*. However, there is non-zero usage recorded at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eighthed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3. [What corpus did Google use???]